# How to update from a original XP no service pack to XP3 with no internet

Tags: windows-xp, updates

First off I used to be an XP guy and I still have the copy that I bought back in 2002. I had to downgrade my computer to an old iMac I had in storage and the only copy that I have of XP (I really do not want to buy a new one) is the old copy. I installed into a fully formatted drive and then realised that this XP disc came out before service pack 1. Which means that there really is no support for this. Next I noticed that the ethernet driver is unrecognized (big shock) therefore I have no internet, so I cannot install using windows update. Therefore I do not have any updates (again this disc is very old) and no access to the internet.

I have another computer that I can burn discs off of and it has the internet but I will not have it for much longer.

The device I installed the XP on is an 20-inch iMac (Early 2006), 2.0 GHz Intel(R) CPU T2500 with 1.98GB RAM

Is it possible to update my machine and be able to do use it the way it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I managed it was that I downloaded found an executable version of SP1a and then updated the system by moving the file over, then I downloaded the service pack SP3 ISO, updated the system.

However it didn't fix the ethernet driver and since I had no idea what the controller's actual name nor the company that made it, I moved over the Auslogics System Information, did a diagnostics took the problem devices "Value" and did research in order to find the needed information, and got the driver and moved it over. Yay monotony.